# How to place images in a linear layout using DragEvent

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a drag puzzle where I move one image to a LinearLayout in order to solve the puzzle.

When I place one image to one of the LinearLayouts is all good but I don't want any other picture to be placed in that same LinearLayout, another problem is when I drag the image outside the LinearLayout and I drop the image the image disappears.

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    View vista;
    LinearLayout layout1, layout2, layout3, layout4, layout5, layout6;
    ImageView image1, image2, image3;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public BlankFragment() 
    {

    }

    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) 
    {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener 
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
        {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener 
    {
        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        image1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image1.setOnTouchListener(new BlankFragment.MyTouchListener());

        image2 = vista.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image2.setOnTouchListener(new BlankFragment.MyTouchListener());

        image3 = vista.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image3.setOnTouchListener(new BlankFragment.MyTouchListener());

        layout1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        layout2 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout2.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        layout3 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        layout3.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        layout4 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout4);
        layout4.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        layout5 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout5);
        layout5.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        layout6 = vista.findViewById(R.id.layout6);
        layout6.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        return vista;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) 
    {
        if (mListener != null) 
        {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) 
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) 
        {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() 
    {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener 
    {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And here is my layout
[image: normal image]

and I don't want this to happen
[image: two images in the same LinearLayout]

just only one per LinearLayout and the thing about moving an image outside the LinearLayouts that makes disappear the image

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and [this](https://github.com/francislainy/world-cup-match-simulator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/francislainy/campos/worldcupmatchsimulator/fragments/TeamGroupFragment.java) piece  of code may help you.

Basically you need to have a temporary view to hold the view your dragging and also remove the view that may be already contained inside the layout.

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        for (LinearLayout layout : layouts) {

            if (layout.getChildCount() == 0) {

                layout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            }
        }


        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return true;

    }
}


private class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        int action = dragEvent.getAction();

        switch (action) {

            case ACTION_DROP:

                View viewBeingHold = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) viewBeingHold.getParent();

                owner.removeView(viewBeingHold);
                LinearLayout containerWhereViewWillBeDropped = (LinearLayout) view;
                viewBeingHold.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                View viewAlreadyOnLayout = containerWhereViewWillBeDropped.getChildAt(0);

                if (viewAlreadyOnLayout != null) {

                    containerWhereViewWillBeDropped.removeView(viewAlreadyOnLayout);

                    containerWhereViewWillBeDropped.addView(viewBeingHold);

                    owner.addView(viewAlreadyOnLayout);

                } else if (viewAlreadyOnLayout == null) {// it means we're still on the same layout
                    owner.addView(viewBeingHold);

                }

                updateDatabaseWithTeamPosition();

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I'm trying to implement the snipet that you gave me but  sadly it doesnt work for my problem but it gave me an idea of how to solve it :)

Comment: Cool! Glad to help. Hope you get your issue solved. :)